Harmonic Quantum Oscillator ODE Python
So, we have to calculate eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for this one assignment. In short, we are using a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator.
If you want to read the full thing , Here:
The probability density evolution in a one-dimensional harmonic trapping potential is governed by the partial differential equation: $$i\hbar \psi_t + \frac{\hbar}{2m}\psi_{xx}-V(x)\psi=0$$ where $|\psi|^2$ is the probability density and $V(x)=kx^2/2$ is the harmonic confining potential. A typical solution technique for this problem is to assume a solution of the form $$\psi = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \phi_n(x)\text{exp}(-i \frac{E_n}{2\hbar}t)$$ which is called an eigenfunction expansion solution, where $\phi_n$ is our eigenfunction and $E_n$ is our eigenvalue.Plugging this solution to $i\hbar \psi_t + \frac{\hbar}{2m}\psi_{xx}-V(x)\psi=0$ gives theboundary value problem: $$\frac{d^2\phi_n}{dx^2}-[Kx^2-\epsilon_n]\phi_n=0$$ where we expect the solution $\phi_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ and $\epsilon_n$ is the quantum energy. Note that here $K=km/\hbar^2$ and $\epsilon_n=E_nm/\hbar^2$. In what follows, take $K=1$ and always normalize so that $\int^\infty_\infty |\phi_n|^2dx=1$.
Calculate the first five normalized eigenfunctions, $\phi_n$, and eigenvalues, $\epsilon_n$, using a shooting scheme. For this calculation, use $x \in [-L, L]$ with $L=4$ and choose $xspan=-L:0.1:L$. Save the absolute value of the eigenfunctions in a 5 column matrix (column 1 is $\phi_1$, column 2 is $\phi_2$) and the eigenvalues in a 1x5 vector.
Answers should be A1 as our eigenfunctions and A2 as our eigenvalues.
Here is my code so far:
#Original Good
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define constants and domain
L = 4
xspan = np.arange(-L, L + 0.1, 0.1)
N = 5  # Number of eigenfunctions
A2 = np.zeros(N)
A1 = np.zeros((len(xspan), N))

# Define the harmonic potential V(x) = x^2 (K is already set to 1)
def V(x):
    return x**2

# System of ODEs for shooting method (phi and phi')
def schrodinger_ode(y, x, epsilon):
    phi = y[0]
    dphi_dx = y[1]
    d2phi_dx2 = (V(x) - epsilon) * phi
    return [dphi_dx, d2phi_dx2]

# Function to compute the solution and normalize it
def solve_eigenfunction(epsilon, xspan):
    # Initial conditions (shooting method)
    phi0 = [1e-5, 1e-5]  # Small non-zero values for starting the integration
    
    # Solve the Schrödinger ODE using odeint
    sol = odeint(schrodinger_ode, phi0, xspan, args=(epsilon,))
    
    # Extract the eigenfunction
    phi = sol[:, 0]
    
    # Normalize the eigenfunction
    norm = np.sqrt(np.trapz(np.abs(phi)**2, xspan))
    phi_normalized = phi / norm
    return phi_normalized  # Returning the normalized eigenfunction

# Loop to calculate the first 5 eigenfunctions and eigenvalues using the shooting method
for n in range(N):
    # Guess for the eigenvalue (epsilon_n)
    epsilon_guess = 2 * n + 1  # Based on the harmonic oscillator
    
    # Refine the eigenvalue guess using the shooting method
    epsilon_n = epsilon_guess
    phi_n = solve_eigenfunction(epsilon_n, xspan)
    
    # Save the normalized eigenfunction and eigenvalue
    A1[:, n] = np.abs(phi_n)  # Use absolute value to match problem's requirement
    A2[n] = epsilon_n

# Save the results to npy files
np.save('A1.npy', A1)
np.save('A2.npy', A2)
print(A1)
print(A2)
# Plot the eigenfunctions
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm']  # Different colors for each eigenfunction

for n in range(N):
    plt.plot(xspan, A1[:, n], label=f'Eigenfunction $\\phi_{n+1}(x)$', color=colors[n])

# Customize the plot
plt.title('First Five Normalized Eigenfunctions of the Harmonic Oscillator')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$|\\phi_n(x)|$')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()

The eigenvalues (A2) are correct, but A1 or my eigenfunctions aren't. Here, is the plot I am getting:

Here is what I should be getting (ignoring colors):

I would greatly appreciate if someone can please help me.

You are lucky that you get as much symmetry as that. Your solution might explode away according to the basis solution that behaves like $\exp(\sqrt{K}x^2/2)$. You will need to search for initial values that make the solutions more symmetric, or employ a symmetric integration method.

Thanks, I will definetly try to work on that.

Ignoring the colours I honestly can't see the difference between the plots. Can you describe in more detail the errors you have? Personally I would much prefer some numbers rather than a picture,

The quantum harmonic oscillator has an exact, analytic solution. Have you compared with that? Is that what you are doing in the plots above?

I see a small difference in how the functions decay towards 4. But I would not expect a much better solution. Does it get closer if you increase $L$?

Nitpick: $\psi$ is not the probability density. $|\psi|^2$ is.
